# Disable key input in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView in my form for which I dont want to have key input enabled.
Which means that if I have this tree structure:

```
Root
|
-- Abba
|
-- Basic
|
-- Center
```

...and press <kbd>b</kbd> key. I do not want "Basic" to be selected. I only want the user to be able to select nodes using mouse input.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in key press event of tree view

```
  if(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
  {
       e.Handled = true;
  }
```

Comment: My guts tell me you should write e.Handled = true;

Answer (score 0):

First thought: You could overload the OnKey* events to do nothing.